# Importing custom SVG as editable symbol from Affinity Designer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology, import, svg

How do I export an SVG symbol that I created in Affinity Designer to QGIS in a way that it allows me to edit the properties of the symbol (fill & stroke colour and stroke width) in QGIS?

Preferably, I want these properties to be driven from QGIS, so I don't need to export and reload the SVG to see the changes. I am using QGIS 3.16.

Comment: I found the solution!
You need to remove the style properties:
e.g. style="fill:#f00;stroke:#f00;stroke-width:1px;"/>

And after <path, add: fill="param(fill) #FFF" stroke="param(outline) #000" stroke-width="param(outline-width) 1"